# Streamlining documentation in the implementation file

Tags: xcode

I document my methods in the interface file with something like this:

```
/**
 Returns an foo object containing a new bar value.

 @param newBar The bar value for the new foo. (Possible values: foo or bar)

 @return A foo object containing a calculated value.

 You can specify bar values in the following formats `bar`, `foo`.

 */
```

Xcode generates a nice little pop-up when I i.e. click on the method name with alt.

To accomplish this for my private methods, I have added a `@interface` at the top of my .m-file. In it I declare and document my methods. This works, however it a) separates my documentation from the actual implementation of the method and b) in the quick-jump menu (above the code pane) is clutted because all my documented methods appear twice (once from the `@interface` in italic and once from the `@implementation`).

Is there a better way of doing this? If I document the method in the @implementation Xcode does not seem to generate the pop-up info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an additional header, if your class is `TheInterface`, it can be `TheInferface-Private.h`.

Define and document your private methods and properties on this new header. The documentation works as expected and you'll get ride of the clutter in the jump bar.

It doesn't solve the documentation separated from the implementation issue. I don't see why this is a problem, everybody expects the documentation in a header file.

Having some private methods in a separate header file is handy, some times, in hackish subclasses.